# How can I provide HSTS support in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hsts

In Rails 5 we can do something like:
`config.ssl_options = { hsts: { expires: 10.days } }`

I found an old article that says I can enforce it with

```rb
  before_filter :strict_transport_security
  def strict_transport_security
    if request.ssl?
      response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    end
  end
```

In this file there is a HSTS method, does this mean it is on by default in Rails 4.2?
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb

Comment: I've just seen   
`# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
 config.force_ssl = true` does this set hsts in ssl options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 5 added more options that you can specify in `ssl_options`, but rails 4 already had basic ones, including `hsts: { expires: 10.days, subdomains: false }`, as you see in code.

```rb
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = { hsts: { expires: 10.days, subdomains: false } }
```

Comment: So I can set hsts: { expires: 10.days, subdomains: false } in config.ssl_options?

Comment: @CJW yes, similar to rails 5